# Sitecore WFFM with sensitive data

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore7, web-forms-for-marketers

Can i use WFFM in sitecore to capture sensitive data like user personal and banking details? Can someone please provide me what is the best approach?

Answer (score 3):

Although the first article I wrote -- the article shared by Martin -- will meet your requirements, I strongly recommend checking with the laws of your country first to ensure you are able to do this legally.

Answer (score 1):

There are several articles which may be useful to you here:

- http://sitecorejunkie.com/2013/06/21/encrypt-web-forms-for-marketers-fields-in-sitecore/
- http://sitecorejunkie.com/2013/01/19/rip-out-sitecore-web-forms-for-marketers-field-values-during-a-custom-save-action/

The author has done a lot of work with secure WFFM forms.

He also did a presentation that might be relevant to you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nrh8xEYS5NA

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this in sitecore 8, you need to override methods `InsertFormData` and `GetFormData` in class `Sitecore.WFFM.Analytics.Providers.AnalyticsFormsDataProvider`. This will encrypt data being stored in mongo's `FormData` table.

You might also want to override classes `CombinedFormsDataProvider` and `SqlFormsDataProvider` in case you switch to using SQL server as WFFM data store.

You will also need to encrypt aggregation data in SQL server reporting db. You do this by overriding `Sitecore.WFFM.Analytics.Aggregation.Processors.FormSummary.FormSummaryProcessor`. This will encrypt data being stored in `FormFieldValues` table.

- Do not forget to patch the config files to use your class instead of default ones.

See this blog for full solution:
http://josedbaez.com/2016/09/wffm-encryption/